# How to move group div to the new line when there is not enough space?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have HTML block:

```
 <div class="block_wrapper">
        <div class="block">
         Show by
          <div class="badges">
              <app-badge _ngcontent-xbm-c7="" _nghost-xbm-c15="" ng-reflect-badge="[object Object]" ng-reflect-css-class="primary" ng-reflect-is-selected="false"><span _ngcontent-xbm-c15="" class="badge p-2 mb-1 mr-2 badge-unchecked" ng-reflect-klass="badge p-2 mb-1 mr-2" ng-reflect-ng-class="badge-unchecked">10</span></app-badge>
              <app-badge _ngcontent-xbm-c7="" _nghost-xbm-c15="" ng-reflect-badge="[object Object]" ng-reflect-css-class="primary" ng-reflect-is-selected="false"><span _ngcontent-xbm-c15="" class="badge p-2 mb-1 mr-2 badge-unchecked" ng-reflect-klass="badge p-2 mb-1 mr-2" ng-reflect-ng-class="badge-unchecked">10</span></app-badge>
              <app-badge _ngcontent-xbm-c7="" _nghost-xbm-c15="" ng-reflect-badge="[object Object]" ng-reflect-css-class="primary" ng-reflect-is-selected="false"><span _ngcontent-xbm-c15="" class="badge p-2 mb-1 mr-2 badge-unchecked" ng-reflect-klass="badge p-2 mb-1 mr-2" ng-reflect-ng-class="badge-unchecked">10</span></app-badge>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now it looks like:

[image]

If there is not space it becomes to:

[image]

How to move `<div class="badges">` to the new line if there is not free space?

It is question about flex blocks, that are inline but when space is not enought they should be one after one.

**CSS is:**

```
.block_wrapper {
   display: flex;
}

.block {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that includes the relevant CSS and HTML

Comment: Please show your CSS

Comment: Done, see CSS in question again

Comment: Show your actual HTML, or something more representative, not "..."

Comment: `flex-direction: column;`

Comment: By default it should be row, but if not space column

Comment: Looks like you have a lot more classes in use in your HTML than you are showing in your CSS. Does your CSS define properties for those classes?

Comment: You don't show your CSS for `badges` or `badge` class. So I'm taking a semi-blind stab here, but you could try `.badges { display: inline-block; }`. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mbratch/crkm1ny7/7/). You don't really need the `flex` for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your block class try adding this css

```
.block {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

Normally it will align in same line but if there is not enough space it will move to newline